# Javascript - sql.js select drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, sql.js

I'm trying to use sql.js to retrieve data from my local database and later on make modifications. I'm trying to create a select drop down, however when I try to simply display the output in a div, it only shows me the last value. I would like to have the same output as the console which is displaying all the data.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="test">
</div>

<script src="sql.js"></script>

<script>

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'test.sqlite', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
var db = new SQL.Database(uInt8Array);

db.each("SELECT user_name FROM users",

function(row){document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = (row.user_name )});
};

xhr.send();

</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the line read

```
db.each("SELECT user_name FROM users",

function(row){document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML+ (row.user_name )});
};
```

Comment: That doesn't work and I don't want to concatenate the result. I'm trying to use a for each but it's not liking it either.

Comment: If I am understanding what you are trying to do aka loop over a collection of names and add each to an html element, then there is no other way I can think of than concatenation. If you don't want to continuously reference the actual html object in each iteration of the loop then you concatenate onto a string variable in the loop and then put that variable in the html element.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how that's possible because I only get the last value in my database. There's nothing I can concatenate. I might be missing the point completely but what I'm trying to do is for each item from my result, to display it. Are we on the same page or there's something I'm missing from your answer? I appreciate your input.

Comment: You are getting only the last value because you are resetting "document.getElementById("test").innerHTML" every time the function is called (if you set this element to equal "a" and then you reset it to equal "b" then it will render just "b" not "ab"), which happens to be for every user_name you have in your database. So "document.getElementById("test").innerHTML" is going to equal the last element in your collection. If you declare a null string before your loop and concatenate onto it each element in your collection, at the end of your loop your string will contain all of the elements.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much for your help. I did add concatenate the value with the innerHTML which works great. To get to a drop down, would you suggest using a function?

Comment: I suggest declaring the concatenation string to equal "<select>" when you first declare it and then the code to read                                   function(row){concatString = concatString + "<option>" + (row.user_name ) + "</option>"});
};   concatString = concatString + "</select>"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, happy coding!